# 1120: Access of undefined property squareSpeed

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, undefined

Ok so I've tried a few solutions from similar problems I've seen answered but haven't been able to solve this problem. Here's the code....

```
package {

import flash.events.*;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import Game.C;

public class GameController extends MovieClip {
    public function startGame() {
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);
    }

    function gameLoop(evt: Event): void {

        //Handle User Input

        //Handle Game Logic

        cpuSquare.x += C.squareSpeed;
        cpuSquare.y += C.squareSpeed;

        //Handle Display


    }
}
}
```

then from the game package...

```
package Game
{

public class C 
{
    public var squareSpeed:int = 3;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to refer to a static property. Static properties are those that belong to the class as opposed to an instance of that class.

To fix this, you have to make squareSpeed a static property.

`public static var squareSpeed:int = 3`

Otherwise you will have to make an instance of C and use that instead, but I don't think that's what you're trying to do here.

Here's how you would do that just in case.

```
var cInstance:C = new C();
cpuSquare.x += cInstance.squareSpeed;
cpuSquare.y += cInstance.squareSpeed;
```

Comment: Ok thanks! I'm new to as3 and utilizing multiple files so I really appreciate it.